# Python - cannot use Selenium to hit the final print button

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, printing, driver

I try to write the code for the web automation, which is: open a tab, login, hit button, and print the page.
Everything is running perfect except the last step, which my script cannot click the blue "Print" button shown below.
Thanks for the help!

[image]

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import logging

def chrome_script():

    driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\\Users\\Eric\\chromedriver')
    driver.get("https://shop.spira.com/Admin/Orders/Default.aspx")
    driver.implicitly_wait(2)

    driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_MainContent_LoginDialog1_UserName")
    driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_MainContent_LoginDialog1_Password")

    driver.find_element_by_id("LoginButton")


    driver.find_element_by_name("ctl00$MainContent$BatchButton").click()

    time.sleep(2)

    driver.find_element_by_name("ctl00$MainContent$Print").click()

    driver.forward()

    driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//button[text()="Print"]').click()


    time.sleep(5)

    return

chrome_script()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not HTML, that's part of Chrome's UI. You can tell this by trying to right-click on the dialog and you don't get the context menu.

You could try sending CTRL+SHIFT+P to open the system print dialog and then ALT+P to print.

Comment: I tried this way but it seems cannot print either, with exit code 0. 
Thanks for the help~

Comment: I used     
pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'shift', 'p')
pyautogui.hotkey('alt', 'p')
it works, thanks

Comment: If this, or any other answer, was useful please upvote it. Once you find the answer to your question, please mark it as accepted so the question isn't left unanswered.